# Expansion of bash variable in multiple quotes?

Tags: bash, variables, curl, expansion

I am trying to perform a cURL command within a bash script to POST to a URI. The command requires that one of the arguments be surrounded by double and single quotes i.e. `'"jsimmons"'` In my script however this argument is a variable so the command keeps failing which I believe is because the variable is doing some weird expansion and the command is losing the quotes necessary.

For my current attempt, which doesn't work, the argument looks like, `'""$watcher""'` as I am trying to expand the variable and place that string within the double and single quotes.

How can I expand my variable properly to fulfill the requirements of the command?

Comment: Atleast paste the relevant part of the code and the error you are facing

Comment: XY problem: Are you trying to JSON-encode the string `jsimmons`?

Comment: If the outermost quotes are single quotes, the current shell will not expand the variable reference inside the string.  There are no escape characters inside a single-quoted string.  The next single quote unconditionally ends the string, regardless of backslashes or any other 'escape' characters.

Comment: In order to give you more specific advice, it would be could if you showed us exactly what the value of `$jsimmons` is and an example of the command you're trying to produce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have double quotes around your whole command, you can insert single quotes without any trouble but need to escape double quotes.

For example:

```
$ watcher=jsimmons
$ echo "'\"$watcher\"'"
'"jsimmons"'
```

Comment: I suspect the single quotes aren't actually necessary beyond ensuring that the double quotes are passed literally.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the surrounding `'`s and `"`s with `\`

`\'\"$watcher\"\'`

Comment: What do you expect `\'` to do?

Comment: If they are unescaped, the `$watcher` variable will not get expanded, thus it will result to `\"$watcher\"`. Also `\"` does not get expanded since "Within single quotes, every special character except `'` gets interpreted literally," http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html